# Containers in StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

A few weeks ago I come with the following doubt:

When creating a Container (using the connect in a view component that you want to put a logic using redux) for example a HeaderContainer that has a button that calls a dispatch that does something, if I combine it with StackNavigator and I move between screens which each has its HeaderContainer click on the button dispatched the number of times that there are views in the stack (should be the single dispatch but the other views did not end their life cycle component and they are in the stack this happens). Have an idea how can you fix it so that does not happen?

HeaderContainer for each screen
[image]

Clicking will launch several dispatch
[image]

the header is useful to compare in each view, click on each view of the stack.

This is a specific case, but it happens to me with all the containers that are in the navigation stack.

Post Original: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105179/containers-en-stacknavigator

Answer (score 0):

Each view is stacked on top of each other when using StackNavigator. You can use [NavigationActions.reset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Reset) so that only the visible view is in the stack.